# Things to keep all manner of bugs away from home?

Tags: insect

This seemed like a decent place to ask this question.

I have incredible amounts of wasps, bees spiders around my home (specifically on my porch and around my workout station outside). I also have a big issue with random sorts of bugs hovering around my porch light. I know that all of this is normal, but it's also incredibly frustrating to get a mouth full of insects as I walk out of my door at night, and annoying to traverse 6 wasps to get down my steps.

Are there wasp insecticides that keep them away? Or perhaps some scents that they dislike? I'm willing to spend money on this. It aggravates me to no end.

Thank you.

Edit: I live in West Virginia. The things I am trying to get rid of are wasps (red and black), bees (I don't want the bees dead, but to leave my porch and workout station alone). The ones near my light are all over the place at night. I have some moths, and some insects that are much too tiny for me to classify. Just hate them flying into my mouth and eyes as I walk outside.

Again: any scents, insecticides, or traps that get rid of these nuisances?

Comment: Screens are nice, and I've eliminated a wasp nest or four with a firecracker taped to the end of a long stick. Where do you live? swamps, lakes or creeks nearby?

Comment: get yellow porch lights and a bug zapper. get a wasp trap that you fill with orange-juice, they work. remove weeds and flowers (incl on ground like clover, violets) to repeal bees. 1p murphy's oil soap to 8p water in a spray bottle will INSTANTLY kill flys. i've blasted the little suckers right out of the air and they didn't move once they hit the floor. once the winged bugs are gone the spiders will crawl away.

Answer (score 1):

I have a horse farm so there are always some flies under the covered areas on hot days even when using bugs that eat fly larva and fly traps (both helped reduce the number of flies) however the best solution we have found is a large fan set at the lowest level blowing across the area, the flies go other places. We have wasps & hornets but they don't tend to stay where the air is moving.

Comment: I learned something today.